# how to put multiple images to pdf using pdfkit (node js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

what i wanted is paste multiple images from multilpe url.
to do so im downloading and one by one appending to pdf
but the problem is code is not synchronous. And I'm new to node / javascript.

here is my code and error
please help me

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://cdn.pixabay.com/ers90__340.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});

// Create a document
const doc = new PDFDocument();

// Pipe its output somewhere, like to a file or HTTP response
// See below for browser usage
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));

// Embed a font, set the font size, and render some text
doc
  //.font('fonts/PalatinoBold.ttf')
  .fontSize(25)
  .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);

// Add an image, constrain it to a given size, and center it vertically and horizontally
doc.image('google.png', {
  fit: [250, 300],
  align: 'center',
  valign: 'center'
});
// Apply some transforms and render an SVG path with the 'even-odd' fill rule
doc
  .scale(0.6)
  .translate(470, -380)
  .path('M 250,75 L 323,301 131,161 369,161 177,301 z')
  .fill('red', 'even-odd')
  .restore();

// Add some text with annotations
doc
  .addPage()
  .fillColor('blue')
  .text('Here is a link!', 100, 100)
  .underline(100, 100, 160, 27, { color: '#0000FF' })
  .link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/');

// Finalize PDF file
doc.end();
```

error: this is what im getting when running
before downloading the image pdfkit module runs its code
i dont know how to synchronise

```
internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google.png'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
    at Function.open (/Users/sharan/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4432:19)
    at PDFDocument.openImage (/Users/sharan/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4575:24)
    at PDFDocument.image (/Users/sharan/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4476:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sharan/Desktop/jsss/var8.js:32:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'google.png'
}
```

Comment: Share the code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ....

```js
ImagesUrlArr.forEach(function (el){
    doc.addPage().image(el.data, {fit: [500, 400], align: 'center',valign: 'center'})
})
```

Comment: im new to node js, what is el here??

Comment: @rustiver el is element of array